# How to connect database in Perl program

Tags: database, perl, connection

I have to make some scripts in my server using Perl program. So anyone please help me what is the command for running a simple Perl program with database connection and how to check whether it is connected to the database or not? I am new in Perl. Please help me anyone.

Comment: this question needs some research applied before asking, try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383015/connecting-to-the-database-perl?rq=1)  or many other places and then ask specific questions when you encounter difficulty.

Comment: sorry,can you please just explain how to run a perl program,what is the command for that?

Comment: http://learn.perl.org/ may be helpful! various getting started guides

Answer (score 0):

First open an editor, write some perl program and save it with `.pl` extension. Now to run this program in a simple way open a terminal/command prompt, go to on the same path where you have saved your program. and type `perl yourprogramName.pl`.

To connect with database use `DBI` module. see this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "test";
my $user = "test";
my $password = "test";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:$driver:$database", $user, $password) or die "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

for more see the `perldoc DBI`.